# Splash screen with heavy codes in monotouch

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, xamarin.ios, splash-screen

We now that in monotouch and for iPhone / ipad application when we want to have splash screen before app lunch we should to set launch image in info.plist file and it will show this image before application launches.

But what is the best way to implement a splash screen when we want to have a splash that runs some heavy codes in background and not disappear until these operations had not completed? Some codes like downloading application config from internet and saving theme that often used in splash screen.

Comment: About "Also how we can use some object like progress bar and labels in monotouch and iPhone and iPad applications ?" - please create separated question. It's site rules.

Comment: Ow, OK.sure. I'm sorry about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BTW, there is another solution: create main `UIViewController`, set it as `Window.RootViewController` immediately in AppDelegate's `FinishedLaunching` method. Then create and show modally `splashViewController` by this code:

```cs
    ...
    MainViewController.PresentModalViewController(splashViewController, true);
    ...
```

Hiding modal `UIViewController` is possible via calling code:

```
    DismissModalViewControllerAnimated(true);
```

Note that since iOS 6 `PresentModalViewController` becomes deprecated method. So, for many iOS versions compatibility you could code special method for showing modal `UIViewController`.

```cs
    public void ShowModalViewController (UIViewController vc, bool animated)
    {
        if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(6, 0)) {
            MainViewController.PresentViewController(vc, animated, null);
        } else {
            MainViewController.PresentModalViewController(vc, animated);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Possible solution:

- Make a `SplashViewController`, which contains same image as app's splash image. Also it contains `UIActivityIndicatorView`;
- In `AppDelegate`'s FinishedLaunching method make new instance of `SplashViewController`, set it as `window.RootViewController`, call:

```cs
activityIndicator.StartAnimating();
```

- Runs some heavy codes in background;
- When it's done, set `window.RootViewController` to ViewController, which is app's starting point.

Comment: How can I creat SplashViewController? Is this same as iPhoneViewController or UniversalViewController that designd for splash? can you show me a tutorial for this?

Comment: Also do you know any tutorials about UIActivityIndicatorView? I'm a new developer about monotouch and iPhone.

Comment: Create new UIViewController and name it SplashViewController. Then set it to window.RootViewController. UIActivityIndicatorView is subclass of UIView. Just add it to View via View.AddSubView() method in UIViewController's ViewDidLoad method. Then call StartAnimating().

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong about that solution. I recommend you to use modal view controller instead of rewriting AppDelegate's window property. See example at https://bitbucket.org/MaximKorobov/monotouch-splashtest.