# Cannot back from splashviewcontroller to startpoint of application monotouch

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios, splash-screen

We know that when we want to show a custom splash that be shown until some heavy codes is running we can use splashviewcontroller ( for more information see [Splash screen with heavy codes monotouch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14621022/splash-screen-with-heavy-codes-in-monotouch). i use this codes for this propose and works good. but i don't know when application went to the splashviewcontroller and the heavy code had completed how to set that it go to the start point of application.

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
{
    window = new UIWindow (UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);
    SplashViewController splash= new SplashViewController ();
    window .RootViewController = splash;
    window.MakeKeyAndVisible ();
    return true;
}
```

in splashviewcontroller.cs

```
public override void ViewDidLoad ()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad ();
    UIActivityIndicatorView uai= new UIActivityIndicatorView (UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.Gray);
    View .AddSubview (uai);
    uai.StartAnimating ();
    splashImage .StartAnimating ();
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem (o =>heavyCode ());
}

public void heavyCode ()
{
    int j=0;
    for (int i=0; i<1000000; i++) {
        j++;
    }
    //Should go to start point of application :-S
}
```

I'm a new developer on monotouch and maybe this was a dummy question but had confused me in some days.

I changed heavyCode method to this:

```
public void heavyCode ()
{
    int j=0;
    for (int i=0; i<1000000; i++) {
        j++;
    }
    HomeScreen homescreen = new HomeScreen ();
    App.Delegate .Window .RootViewController = homescreen ;
}
```

and i got this exception:

```
FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: MonoTouch.Foundation.ModelNotImplementedException
```