# Pushing to viewController from appDelegate monoTouch

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios

I am trying to setup a Getting started viewController. In the appDelegate I want to create a if condition that checks for a NSUserDefaults Like this:

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
        {

            if (NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.StringForKey ("LaunchWatcher") != null) {



            } else {


            }


            return true;
        }
```

If LaunchWatcher is not null, appDelegate should push to NewTrackTraceViewController. If null then to TrackTraceViewController. How can I do this using C#? What would be the correct code to push to the viewcontroller?

Something like this:

```
if (NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.StringForKey ("LaunchWatcher") != null) {

this.PresentViewController(NewTrackTraceViewController, animated, null);

            } else {

this.PresentViewController(TrackTraceViewController, animated, null);
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look here:

[Monotouch navigate from splash screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15323332/monotouch-navigate-from-splash-screen/15324565#15324565)

Its basicly what you have to do. Just use the topviewcontroller.

Answer (score 0):

You have to construct view controller,then navigation controller, and assign it to window.

Comment: But is it possible to have 2 rootviewcontrollers? And then choose either one 1 or 2?