# App closes when long-running code is executed during splash

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios, splash-screen

Some months ago, I asked a question about making a splash screen with long-running code on monotouch.

[Splash screen with heavy codes in monotouch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14621022/splash-screen-with-heavy-codes-in-monotouch)

I followed the answer. Now the question is, when I use `ModalViewController` how can I close the app in a normal way when the long-running operation fails?

For example, my long-running code is downloading some configs from server. Then, the download fails. I show a `UIAlertView` to the user that reads, "Download failed, continue?". When user taps 'Yes', the app continues, but what about 'No'? What should I do?

I believe that the best option is closing the app, but I found that it is not recommended and the app may be rejected during the app approval process. So, I just hide the AlertView and ask the user to press the 'Home Button' to close the app. However, when user starts the app again, the application is not starting from `root`, rather it is just resuming from the previous state.

Comment: probably best is to re-try the download operation if you're in the error state and your app is put in the background and brought forward again. Your app delegate will get messages when your app is put in the background

Comment: I know this. But what if user select that i do not want to continue. Or suppose that device is not connected to the internet. in this way user should close the app and connect to the internet and then reopen the app. How we can create the splash that when user close the app it start from its root again

Comment: Really this is so bad, even when the screen open from device home screen the didappear or willappear method not call. :( :(

Comment: I think if the user closes the app then returns, you should try connecting again (in response to the user's action). Then say "could not connect" if you still can't connect.

Comment: You should also use the reachability API to that you can retry if the user gains a network connection. Basically do what the App Store app does.

Comment: OK. it is good. but i do not know how to detect when user returns. When user returns from device home screen to my app any of didappear or didload method of my view not fires.

Comment: not did load. In your app delegate implement `-applicationWillEnterForeground` (and `-applicationWillResignActive:`)

Comment: You can also use `NSNotificationCenter` if you need to respond to these messages inside a controller.

Comment: applicationWillEnterForeground  works, thanks :)